# Getting RoboCopy to copy only completed files

Tags: powershell

I have an issue targeting the right files with robocopy in a folder.

I'm putting together a PowerShell script to copy a file from a folder to another folder to queue it for FTP upload. I want to copy last days file (it's a temperature log from a weather station), which is written to disk at 0:59 am. The problem is that the logging software also keeps the current days file in the folder, constantly writing to it. As such, I can't target the specific file with /minage /maxage as I normally would. I can't either use the /minage:1 /maxage:2 trick, since I need to copy yesterdays file daily, not the "day before yesterday" file.

My guess is I need to target the specific date in the file name, but that's a bit past my current skill level.

The robocopy command I'm using without success is `robocopy $source .\ /maxage:1 /sec /copy:datsou /s /e`

The file name structure is `TAAVG1M_YYYYMMDD`

UPDATE:
Okay, I looked into it a bit more. I can get today's date in the correct format with `Get-Date -format yyyyMMdd` and I can get yesterdays date with `(Get-Date).adddays(-1)`. But what I can't figure out is how to combine the commands into one that get's me yesterdays date in the right format.

Comment: Is it only the one file? Or perhaps all the files have the same date suffix. You could just use your get-date logic with Get-Item?

Comment: Yeah, it's one file per day that I'm trying to fetch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Robocopy is a great utility but I don't think you need that versatility for the example you are giving. You could just use `Get-Item` to get all of yesterdays files and do a simple copy. Something simple like this would copy all files in the source that end with yesterdays date to the destination folder

```
$yesterdaysDate = (Get-Date).adddays(-1).ToString("yyyyMMdd")
Get-Item  -Filter "*$yesterdaysDate" -Path $source | Copy-Item -Destination $destination
```

Comment: Great, that's exactly what I need, except that I can't get it to work, PS complains about Copy-Item doesn't accept pipeline input?

Comment: Here's the full script:
`$yesterdaysDate = (Get-Date).adddays(-1).ToString("yyyyMMdd")
$source = "C:\Observations\TimeSeries\H_TAAVG1M\2016\"
$destination = "C:\FTP\"
Get-Item  -Filter "*$yesterdaysDate" -Path $source | Copy-Item $destination`

Comment: Okey, I got the Get-Item part working (needed to add .txt after $yesterdaysDate, silly me). But Copy-Item still complains, I get this error: `CategoryInfo: InvalidArgument (C:\Observations...1M_20160130.txt:PSObject) [Copy-Item], ParameterBindingException`

Comment: Ok, I figured it out now, I just wrapped Get-Item as a variable and used that as path in Copy-Item, don't know how it took me so long to figure it out. :) Thanks for all the help!

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to get a date as a formatted string:

- The `DateTime` object's [`ToString()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zdtaw1bw.aspx) method:

  ```
  (Get-Date).AddDays(-1).ToString('yyyyMMdd')
  ```
- The [format operator](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/7855.using-the-f-format-operator-in-powershell.aspx) (`-f`):

  ```
  '{0:yyyyMMdd}' -f (Get-Date).AddDays(-1)
  ```
- Calling [`Get-Date`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849887.aspx) a second time with the date you want to format and the parameter `-Format`:

  ```
  Get-Date -Date (Get-Date).AddDays(-1) -Format 'yyyyMMdd'
  ```